# Upgradeable contracts and the external / eternal storage pattern

Tags: solidity, hardhat, upgrading

An upgradable contract I'm writing in Solidity with Hardhat has become too large to deploy and needs to be split. Fortunately there are some clear distinct features across which it can be split, but I'm unsure how to do it while retaining upgradeability and ensuring the main contract controls permissions of what can be done with the auxiliary contracts.

So far this is the plan:

- Implement both the main contract and the auxiliary contracts as upgradable contracts (with OpenZeppelin's "transparent" framework)
- The main contract will implement some basic features, among others are a list of admin addresses and functions to manage it. Among others, the main contract will implement a `function isAdmin(address a) external returns (bool)`.
- The main contract will itself implement proxy functions for the functions implemented by the auxiliary contracts. The external caller sees it as if it implements the entire set of functionalities
- The auxiliary upgradable contracts will implement an `initialize()` function which accepts the address of the main contract's proxy contract, and will call its `isAdmin()` whenever it needs to decide if an operation can be carried out.
- The main contract has a special function which sets the addresses of the deployed auxiliary contract proxies.

If it works, this will essentially make the following sequence very common:

```
[external caller] -> [main proxy] -> [main contract] -> [aux proxy] -> [aux contract] -> [main proxy isAdmin] -> [main contract isAdmin] -> (return to 1st main contract caller)
```

Is there a better way to do it? Will it be too expensive in gas?

And one more question: can I ensure that functions in the auxiliary contracts can only be called by the main contract, not by random wallets?